# Getting a ReadTimeout (System.InvalidOperationException) when trying to serialize a response from S3 to a Stream

Tags: c#, json, .net, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api

I am having problems with a timeout when copying the response from the GetObjectAsync method (AWS S3) to the MemoryStream.

Here's my code:

```
using (GetObjectResponse response = await amazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                    {
                        responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }

                    return memoryStream;
                }
```

And here's the exception I'm getting:

```
file.ReadTimeout = 'file.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Here's the full error thrown on my Swagger:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()

   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)

   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Documentation and previous questions have not helped me so far, any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I am getting the same error. This post seems to be the only mention of this issue anywhere.